# Can I use "Who is you" when I ask a robot?

Tags: auxiliary-verbs

An artificially intelligent robot performs as a human being but it's not a person. If I ask someone else about this robot, I must ask "`What is it?`" *(considering it as an object)* but when I ask this question itself, can I use "`Who is you?`" (considering it as an object who can answer)?

Comment: "Who is you?" doesn't make sense.  The verb *to be* is conjugated as **are** when the subject is **you**.

Comment: What @stangdon said (*Who is you?* is syntactic/semantic garbage). The two ways you could directly ask the robot itself about its identity are ***Who** are you?* (anthropically conferring "conscious entity" status on the robot), or ***What** are you?* (implying you think of the robot as a *thing* rather than a person). Your choice of phrasing depends more on how you think of robots than "grammatical correctness" (which doesn't *yet* have a special case for addressing intelligent machines).

Answer (score 1):

We don't have any artificial intelligences, so there hasn't been any need for language to evolve to support them. However there are many pieces of science fiction that suppose an intelligent robot.

If one supposes an artificial intelligence that can imitate human responses well enough to pass a Turing test, I would imagine that the AI would be quite offended (would imitate offence) at being called a "what" and would want (would imitate desire) to be treated as a "who" at all times. Commander Data in Startrek expected to be treated as a member of the crew, even though he couldn't imitate human emotion.

If you can talk to the AI, using "who" would seem more natural. We already use "who" when talking to dogs — "who's a good boy?"

At any rate, it would have to be "who are you" not "is".